# Changing templateUrl using $rootScope AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to change the `templateUrl` to point to a different file when the user selects a value from a dropdown list using `AngularJS`.

At the moment I have a `SidebarController` which sets the `$rootScope` with the value the user selected:

```
$scope.changeTemplate = function(templateModel){
        $rootScope.themeFolder = templateModel;
    }
```

The HTML

```
<section id='templates'>
        <span>Select your template</span>
        <div class="btn-group">
            <label class="active btn btn-primary" ng-model="templateModel" ng-click='changeTemplate(templateModel)' uib-btn-radio="'t1'">template 1</label>
            <label class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="templateModel" ng-click='changeTemplate(templateModel)'  uib-btn-radio="'t2'">template 2</label>
            <label class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="templateModel" ng-click='changeTemplate(templateModel)' uib-btn-radio="'t3'">Template 3</label>
            <label class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="templateModel" ng-click='changeTemplate(templateModel)'  uib-btn-radio="'t4'">Template 4</label>
        </div>
    </section>
```

I then have all of my routing within a seperate file `module.js`

```
application.config(["$stateProvider", function ($stateProvider) {

    var main = {
        name: "MainPage",
        url: "/",
        title: 'My test Angular Site',
        views: {
            "mainContent": {
                templateUrl: 'modules/main/template/t1/home.html',
                controller: "MainPageController"
            },
            "sidebar":{
                templateUrl: "modules/main/template/sidebar.html",
                controller: "SidebarController"
            }
        }
    };
    $stateProvider.state(main);
}]);
```

By default you will notice that it is set to load home.html from the t1 directory. I would like to have this change dynamically when the user selects a different template.

Does anyone have any idea how I might be able to achieve this ?

Thanks,

Comment: you should use dynamic ng-include like: `<div ng-include="templateModel"></div>`

Answer (score 0):

you can use $templateCache to achieve this.
simply make an ajax call to the template and $templateCache.set (...) it to the given route. 
however, this really sounds like a bad idea and i wonder why you would want to do this in the first place. 
i do not think that you should try to change those urls at all. rather solve the problem programatically. but unfortunately i do not know enough about what you want to achieve in the end to be able to give you any further advice.